# How to dynamically invoke non-static System.Object::Equals(object) for this/instance=null (e.g. through reflection)?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, cil

How to dynamically invoke non-static `System.Object::Equals(object)` for this==null?

I have C#:

```
Nullable<Int32> i1 = 33;
Nullable<Int32> i2 = 33;
i1 = null;

var ret = i1.Equals(i2); //note: i1==null
```

Execution after compilation will give `ret` == `false` with no exception. This is the desired behavior.

IL disassemby of line `var ret = i1.Equals(i2);` :

```
IL_001b: ldloca.s     i1
IL_001d: ldloc.1      // i2
IL_001e: box          valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>
IL_0023: constrained. valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>
IL_0029: callvirt     instance bool [System.Runtime]System.Object::Equals(object)
IL_002e: stloc.2      // 'ret'
```

Under the hood - runtime calls the `System.Object::Equals(object)` (IL_0029) method for instance/this == null

If I invoke `System.Object::Equals(object)`method through reflection for this/instance==null, I get an exception `System.Reflection.TargetException` "Non-static method requires a target."

Calling code:

```
Nullable<Int32> i1 = 33;
Nullable<Int32> i2 = 33;
i1 = null;

var equalsMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", 
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

var ret2= equalsMethod.Invoke(i1, new object[] { i2 }); //note: i1==null, throw exception 'Non-static method requires a target.'
```

If in the above code `i1` is set to some number, e.g. `i1 = 3`. the code will execute correctly.

```
i1 = 3;
var equalsMethod = typeof(object)
    .GetMethod("Equals", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
var ret2= equalsMethod.Invoke(i1, new object[] { i2 }); //ret2 will be false
```

I need to dynamically invoke this method.
**I can't change it to the static method** '{Boolean Equals (System.Object, System.Object)}'. I need it in a larger project that dynamically invoke different methods. I present Equals as an example.

After decompile method `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke`. It seems to check if this / instance == null and throw an exception.
Is there any way to bypass this or other way to do this?

Comment: To my knowledge `i1 = null;` does not make `this = null` for anything... I suspect you either need another example OR explanation in the question does not match what you are actually trying to achieve...

Comment: `this` depends on the context. When calling the `System.Object :: Equals (object)` method, for instance==null. ie. i1=null; i1.Equals(i2). in this method (Equals) `this`==null

Comment: You are absolutely right... never cared for boxing nullable types and indeed it will be null there.

Comment: You could always compile a dynamic method using the same IL and cache it off. I know you use Equals as an example, but fortunately there aren't very many other instance methods for Nullable so you wouldn't have to create too many of them. The fact nullable are structs and aren't actually null but get compiler and runtime support to then behave like nulls is a real killer with reflection and dynamic methods usually requiring a bunch of special casing

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - and probably in some form it will come down to it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expression trees to compile this code and invoke it:

```
   Nullable<Int32> i1 = null;
   Nullable<Int32> i2 = 33;
   var equalsMethod = typeof(object)
        .GetMethod("Equals",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
    var call = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(i1, typeof(int?)),
            equalsMethod,
            Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(i2), typeof(object)));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(call).Compile();
    Console.WriteLine(lambda()); // prints false
```

Comment: I modified the `lambda` variable so that there was no explicit bool type: `var lambda = Expression.Lambda(call).Compile (); var  ret = lambda.DynamicInvoke();` and it doing what I need. Thx

Comment: @MikeDev was glad to help!